# JavaFx not loading FXML

Tags: java

I create simple FXML in java and make little bit change of it like adding framework maven into project and changing FXML file into resource folder but when I try to run it it gives following errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)
```

But I change package's name from sample to other name. **When I make name of package into sample it works fine but When I change it other name it dosn't work. what might be problem here??**
[image]

Comment: *`ClassNotFoundException: sample.Main`* since you're trying to run a class which is not present.

Comment: but I refactor it everywhere in project sample was changed to other name why it is still don't run in project

Comment: check the pom.xml if it contains a startup class and check your eclispe run configuration